# Using JS to change the background colour, on multiple element but then change when another element is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of pictures in a table and when one of the pictures is clicked, the background of the *td* changes color. However only one can be selected.

This is what I have so far, however it changes the background of everyone which is clicked:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel1">
      <img src="pic1.jpg" id="setDesign1">
      <script>
        document.getElementById("setDesign1").addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
          return false;
        });
      </script>
    </td>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel2">
      <img src="pic2.jpg" id="setDesign2">
      <script>
        document.getElementById("setDesign2").addEventListener("click", function() {                
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
        });
      </script>
    </td>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel3">
      <img src="pic3.jpg" id="setDesign3">
      <script>
        document.getElementById("setDesign3").addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
          return false;
        });
      </script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: You can have a common function which first removes the background colour styling of all images and then changes the colour of that particular image alone.

Comment: Changes only one background for me on Chrome. Although this is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/731pydqo/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `<input type="radio">`

```css
input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}

.input-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<input 
  type="radio" name="emotion" 
  id="sad" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="sad">
  <img 
    src="//cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-63/24/402_-_Interface_radio_button_off_indeterminate_edit_radio_icon-128.png" 
    alt="I'm sad" />
</label>

<input 
  type="radio" name="emotion"
  id="happy" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="happy">
  <img 
    src="//cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-63/24/402_-_Interface_radio_button_off_indeterminate_edit_radio_icon-128.png" 
    alt="I'm happy" />
</label>
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this and works great apart from the fact it doesnt work on the first image ( there are 6 in total). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the *id* attribute, you can try using *class*. Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the images, then loop through them to attach the **click** event. Inside the event handler function reset the style for all the images and the set the style on to the current element:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".setDesign");

images.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function changeColor() { 
      images.forEach(i => i.parentNode.classList.remove('setStyle'));
      this.parentNode.classList.add('setStyle');
   });
 });
```

```css
.setStyle{
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel1">
      <img src="pic1.jpg" id="setDesign1" class="setDesign">
    </td>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel2">
      <img src="pic2.jpg" id="setDesign2" class="setDesign"> 
    </td>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel3">
      <img src="pic3.jpg" id="setDesign3" class="setDesign">
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it using jquery it will easy,

```
$('img').click(function(this){$('img').not(this).css('color','white')
$(this).css('color','red')
})
```

same way you can do in javascript, make all other img tag background to white and the same item to red.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the `tds` that may be colored using `querySelectorAll` and attach an event listener to the `table`. When click event is fired on the image (it bubbles up to the table) you can color the required `td` element that it is the parent element for the image element and reset color for all the others:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='panel']");
const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    tds.forEach(td => {
      td.style.backgroundColor = event.target.parentElement === td ? 'red' : 'white';
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel1">
      <img src="pic1.jpg" id="setDesign1">
    </td>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel2">
      <img src="pic2.jpg" id="setDesign2">
    </td>
    <td width="100px" valign="top" id="panel3">
      <img src="pic3.jpg" id="setDesign3">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```